Is there a way to connect to Redshift from dBeaver CE on Mac Using a Configuration Profile
I am trying to connect to RedShift using dBeaver CE from my Mac.  One of the other teams in our organization has a document to connect to RedShift using SQLWorkbench, but that is on Windows.  I tried to use those directions ( basically, adding the driver and defining the credentials provider. )  But I think the problem is - in that document CredentialsProvider should be set to AdfsCredentialsProvider which does not work on the Mac.  It generates this error SAML error: WIA only support Windows platform.. ( This makes sense )
I was also trying to figure out what properties do I need to set-up when using Using a Configuration Profile info from amazon
Does anyone know what the set-up should be on the Mac for dBeaver CE to be able to connect to RedShift using AWS Configuration Profile?
